# Error 400 and Error 401

Tags: apex, api, external-services, external-app

good day to all the users

This is my issue, i have 2 environments SO this environments need to send data from sandbox to an app

I insert the data with anonymous Window

For the 1 environment when I insert the data, i can see the data in the UI i'm CMR but when I turn on the debug logs i only se the success and after that I see the Request Bad status 401

For 2 environment is the same thing but i first see the status 400(the status changes) and after that I see the success of inserting the data.

But when I insert this data, this data is able to be seen in salesforce and should do the sending to the external application, but I can not see the information in the external application, I am thinking that this happens because in the external application they do not find the same object and ID as in salesforce.

I'm thinking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HTTP 400

This means that the headers or body of the request were malformed. This could be an invalid JSON or query string, invalid host name, etc. You'd have to doublecheck the data you're sending. When testing, it's often a typo or incorrect content encoding. Refer to the app's online documentation for more information.

## HTTP 401

This typically means that the Authorization header is missing or contains an invalid token. Make sure you have a valid token before attempting to call an API that requires authentication. Other times, there may be a custom header like X-Api-Key that you must calculate or provide. Refer to the app's online documentation for more information.

---

Neither of these errors are Salesforce errors. They are errors coming from the other app. You will want to refer to that app's API or SDK documentation for more information on why you may be getting these errors.